# Kentico CMS: admin page https login issue

Tags: kentico

I am unable to login to CMS admin portal. It's redirecting to https: and giving me an error saying site cannot be reached.

Comment: how can we help you? contact your hosting provider...

Answer (score -1):

Your web.config had a rule in it or your site settings are setup to redirect admin interface to SSL.

To resolve the issue:

- remove the web.config entry
- run a query directly against the database table cms_settingskey and update the key value to false.

Comment: What is the name of the entry and key?

Comment: @Daniel I don't know the specific name of the key but if you look for reroute nodes the OP will find rule nodes in there referring to specific rules.